# latex commands (italic and centring ) custom command

Tags: macros, formatting

I want to ask your assistance in two commands(in latex .tex enviroment) thie first one needs a command which is called redbold, in this command I need form the text red colour and bold style. In the second one I need a command which is called centerit. In this case I need a center align and an italic style. Only the italic style is not working for me here. I hope someone could help me in this task. Have good day, and thanking you in advance for your assistance.

Here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lb}{RGB}{44, 139, 183}
\newcommand\redbold[2]{\textcolor{#1}{{\fontseries{b}\selectfont #2}}}
\newcommand\centerit[2]{{\textit{}}\centering}
\begin{document}

\redbold{red}{red and bold}
\vspace{5em}


\centerit[]{center and italic}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Why did you declare your `\centerit` command to take two arguments but used none of `#1` and `#2` in the replacement text? Besides, you called it with an optional (empty) argument (plus a mandatory one), but you didn't use the syntax for defining a macro that takes an optional argument (that would be `\newcommand{\centerit}[numargs][default]{replacement text}`).

The following should do what you want, I hope:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lb}{RGB}{44, 139, 183}

\newcommand{\redbold}[2]{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont #2}}

\newcommand{\centerit}[1]{%
  \par\begingroup\centering\itshape #1\par\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\redbold{red}{red and bold}
\vspace{5em}

\centerit{center and italic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!

I am sorry I am not good at this topic, it as an simple course in the university and I want to complete these homework like this.
Respect for your assistance.



I wish happy and healthy months for you. :)

Comment: Don't be sorry, I'm glad I could be of assistance... but I hope I didn't do your homework! :-p Thanks for the kind words, I wish you a good health too in these dark days!